# Is there any way to allow a user to choose qt installer language?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt-installer

Qt Installer uses system language as its windows' and the license's language.

Is there any way to allow a user to choose the language? I.e., is there any way to change the language in a script?

Note: I need this for Windows OS.

Comment: Are you referring to the language presented to the user in the Qt installer itself, or the language used by the Qt software after it is installed, or ?

Comment: Well, I see that some installers before installing the software offer a user to choose the language of the installation. I mean the language of the wizard.